# Format Excel Cells with XML

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheetml

I want to generate an Excel programmatically (Salesforce Apex) something similar to below screenshot. The number of Cells, background color of the cells will be decided at the run time and hence using programmatic way.
[image]

To achieve this I tried to apply inline styles for Cell > Data but it seems we can't apply inline styles there. For example styles get applied to first Cell with `ss:StyleID="s66"`. But for the second Cell it doesn't work inline styles in that manner. In my requirement since I can't pre-define the style I need some dynamic way. Can anyone confirm if this is not possible or provide any guidance?

```
<Row>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">Test Sheet1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ><Data ss:Type="String"><Font ss:Color="#FF0000">Sample Text</Font></Data></Cell>

</Row>
```

Comment: Cannot see your picture. Could you use a safe for work host?

Comment: Attachment is correctly showing for me(checked as a guest user too). Media sharing sites are blocked in my office network unfortunately. Anyway what it has is a table with different number of cells/colors but with same width for each row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `XML` you are trying to use is `Office 2003 SpreadsheetML`. The reference is [XML Spreadsheet Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa140066.aspx).

If you look at the "XML Spreadsheet Tag Hierarchy", you will see, that the namespace `ss` is always prefixed there. So it is not the default namespace. The default namespace is `html`. So the `Font`, `B`, `Sup` tags are not prefixed by namespace.

But in current `Excel` versions, if saved as `Office 2003 SpreadsheetML`, the default namespace is set to `xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"` which is `ss`. So if one wants using `html` tags, they must be prefixed by `html`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

 <Worksheet ss:Name="Tabelle1">
  <Table>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><html:Font x:Color="#FF0000">Test</html:Font></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><html:B>E = m c <html:Sup>2</html:Sup></html:B></Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>

</Workbook>
```

Another option would be changing the default namespace to `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"` which is `html`. Then the `html` tags needs not be prefixed by `html` but then the `ss` tags must.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

 <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Tabelle1">
  <ss:Table>
   <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String"><Font x:Color="#FF0000">Test</Font></Data></Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String"><B>E = m c <Sup>2</Sup></B></Data></Cell>
   </ss:Row>
  </ss:Table>
 </ss:Worksheet>

</ss:Workbook>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. One more thing as in OP, will it be possible to change the cell fill color? `<Interior>` tag is what I found for that but can't be a child of `<Data>` it seems

Comment: Inline formatting the cell interior seems not possible. But you really should using `ss:Styles` having `ss:Style` in it and only having the `ss:StyleID` in the cell. The maximum number of single cell styles in a workbiook is limited and frequently using inline formatting will exceed that limit very fast.

Comment: Thanks @Axel Richter. It helps